# Creating redirects from old site via web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp-classic, web-config

I need to redirect some old links from our old website to our new website via the web.config file.
I have setup this so far but it causes a 500 error on our site.

This is the web.config :

```
                <location path="about.aspx">
                <system.webServer>
                <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.ite-exhibitions.com/About" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
                </system.webServer>
                </location>
                <location path="investor_relations.aspx">
                <system.webServer>
                <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.ite-exhibitions.com/Investor-Relations" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
                </system.webServer>
                </location>
                <location path="events.aspx">
                <system.webServer>
                <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.ite-exhibitions.com/Event-Calendar" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
                </system.webServer>
                </location>
```

also tried updating it to this and still no joy. any one have any ideas?

Comment: yeah issue is its kicking a 500 error when applied to the web.config is there a specific place it should go? or is this syntax wrong?

Answer (score 0):

asp classic do not support web.config